# PHP script run once a day without cron

Tags: php, excel

I want to create an excel backup of my db once a day. I used SSH to access my web server but i couldn't install cron, i need a sudoier's password or something. I guess i could contact my web host provider.

But there must be an alternative.

Isn't there a way that i can check if a script was ran?

For example if no one added any entry to the db i wouldn't need to back up the db.

So when someone submits something I use that to initiate to write an excel file. And if someone else submits something on that day, I choose not to write an excel file.

The excel file will have a timestamp of the day excel file_2013-11-11.xls

My only concern is what if two people submit at the same time, the excel file would crash, or get locked up since you couldn't write an excel file at the same time correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup an API for your service and use an external request to trigger the procedure

```
export SECRET=myapitoken
curl http://example.com/api/jobs?id=123&token=$SECRET
```

**Note:** You could put additional security measures in place to limit access. Filtering by IP address would be a cheap, easy-to-implement solution.

Aside from that, if you simply google "web server monitoring" you'll find tons of services available to you

Answer (score -2):

*You* don't install cron, it should be installed by default.

Since it seems you already have shell access you should be able to edit your user's personal cron file with `crontab -e`. Just bear in mind that any jobs in this file will be run as your user, not root, and likely not as the same user as Apache uses. Plan your script permissions accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `crontab`

Run it every one day

```
 0 0 */1 * * /path_to_script
```

The `cron` daemon is a long-running process that executes commands at specific dates and times. You can use this to schedule activities, either as one-time events or as recurring tasks.

*minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)*

The fields are separated by spaces or tabs. The first five are integer patterns and the sixth is the command to be executed. The following table briefly describes each of the fields.

Field   Value   Description

minute  0-59    The exact minute that the command sequence executes

hour    0-23    The hour of the day that the command sequence executes

day     1-31    The day of the month that the command sequence executes

month   1-12    The month of the year that the command sequence executes

weekday     0-6     The day of the week that the command sequence executes. Sunday=0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, and so forth.

command     Special     The complete sequence of commands to be executed. The command string must conform to Bourne shell syntax. Commands, executables (such as scripts), or combinations are acceptable.

Tutorial: http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/